# What does \!^ in csh alias do

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, csh

Note: my shell is csh

An ex-co-worker gave me the following command to put in my `.cshrc`:

`alias bastion 'ssh -L \!^\:<some_ip_address> <username>@<something.com>'`

Note that what is in between <> are actual values.

Now when I run this on my shell, I get the following error: `Bad ! arg selector.`

I've been searching the web for similar uses of `ssh -L` but I haven't found an example that uses this syntax of using the `\!^\` in front of the `:`.

Any idea what this command is actually trying to do and why it's not working?

Comment: (1) What did/does the ex-co-worker say about what the alias does and how to use it? (2) "when I run this" – What *exactly*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a csh user myself but this seem to be history control.

> `!^` gives the first argument of the previous command. This is the same as `!:1` . Remember that, just as the `^` (caret) is the beginning-of-line anchor in regular expressions ( 26.4 ) , `!^` gives the beginning history argument.
>
> ```
> % cat fn fn1 fn2
>  ...
> % more !^
> more fn
> ```

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch11_07.htm

The `\` (I assume) are escapes to prevent the `!^` from being interpreted early (i.e. not when the alias is defined but when it's used). See examples [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch10_03.htm).

So this basically implements argument handling for your alias. The alias is intended to be called with a local port number to bind to¹.

```
$ bastion 8080 
# should be executed as
$ ssh -L 8080:<some_ip_address> <username>@<something.com>

$ bastion 8080 some argument
# is probably (I'm still no csh user) executed as
$ ssh -L 8080:<some_ip_address> <username>@<something.com> some argument
```

As conclusion I assume `Bad ! arg selector.` means there where no arg to select because you tried to run it as `bastion` without port argument.

---

¹ <sub>I assume your replacement `<some_ip_address>` was actually an IP + port? Otherwise the `-L` argument would be a bit strange.</sub>

Comment: An interesting concept. I sometimes missed that Bash and Zsh do not allow alias arguments in between. But than again, we just define a function. :D